# How to fetch one object from nested objects inside arrays

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

**I fetched data from one open API. And from that API I want to show image on my browser. But the problem is inside Images array there are 3 images URL. After using arrays' map method i called the first object [0] but it did not work. I am using React js is my Front-end app.**

**This is my React js component.**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./ActivitiesList.css";
import axios from "axios";

import "./ActivitiesList.css";

function ActivitiesList() {
  const [activities, setactivities] = useState({ data: [] });
  const [show, setshow] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchingData();
  }, []);

  const fetchingData = () => {
    axios
      .get("/activities")
      .then(response => {
        //console.log("response", response);
        setactivities({ data: response.data.data }); 
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <div className="EventList">
      <section className="our-event">
        <div className="grid-container">
          {activities.data.slice(0, show).map((list, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <a
                  href={list.info_url} /
                  style={{
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                    color: "black"
                  }}
                  target="a_blank"
                >
                  <div className="whole">
                    <div className="Personcontainer">
                      <div className="Box">
                        {list.description.images.map((img, index) => {
                          return (
                            <img
                              src={img.url[0]} //IN HERE I TRY TO SHOW FIRST OBJECT
                              alt="pics"
                              style={{ width: "270px", height: "270px" }}
                            />
                          );
                        })}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </a>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        {show < activities.data.length && (
          <button onClick={() => setshow(show + 10)} className="Button">
            loadmore
          </button>
        )}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ActivitiesList;
```

**Here is open API's JSON file.**

```
{
  "meta": {
    "count": "96",
    "next": "http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/activities/?limit=1&start=1"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "f67de4f6-d23e-49a7-b9dd-63d68df533a3",
      "name": {
        "fi": "Purjehdus 1700-luvun tyyliin tykkisluuppi Dianalla",
        "en": "Cannon sloop Diana´s sailings",
        "sv": "Seglingar med kanonslupen Diana",
        "zh": null
      },
      "source_type": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "MyHelsinki"
      },
      "info_url": "https://www.suomenlinnatours.com/en/cannon-sloop-diana?johku_product=7",
      "modified_at": "2020-01-27T09:37:27.221Z",
      "location": {
        "lat": 60.145111083984375,
        "lon": 24.987560272216797,
        "address": {
          "street_address": "Suomenlinna Tykistölahti Pier",
          "postal_code": null,
          "locality": "Helsinki"
        }
      },
      "description": {
        "intro": null,
        "body": "<p>Luvassa on amiraali Chapamin tahdittama mielenkiintoinen laivamatka valistusajan Viaporiin. Dianan purjehduksien aikana nähdään Suomenlinnaa mereltä käsin ja kuullaan saaristolaivaston kiehtovasta historiasta. Osallistujat pääsevät halutessaan avustamaan 1700-luvun univormuihin sonnustautunutta miehistöä purjeiden nostossa ja laskussa, lisäksi muutama reipas pääsee mukaan soutuharjoitukseen.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Purjehdukset lähtevät Suomenlinnan Tykistölahden laiturista. Suomenlinnaan pääsee JT-Linen vesibussilla tai HSL:n lautalla Kauppatorilta (venematka ei kuulu lipun hintaan). Diana on avovene, joten säänmukainen varustus on tärkeä.&nbsp;<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<span><span>Lasten meriseikkailu – perhepurjehdus ajalla 26.6.- 3.8.2019<br />\r\nkeskiviikkoisin, torstaisin ja lauantaisin kello 12.30<br />\r\nElokuun lauantaisin 10.8., 17.8., 24.8. ja 31.8.2019 kello 12.30.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nPurjehdus 1700-luvun tyyliin – yleisöpurjehdus ajalla 26.6.- 3.8.2019:<br />\r\nKeskiviikkoisin, torstaisin ja lauantaisin kello 15.30<br />\r\nElokuun lauantaisin 10.8., 17.8., 24.8. ja 31.8.2019 kello 15.30</span></span><br />\r\n&nbsp;</p>\r\n",
        "images": [ // FROM HERE I WANT TO SHOW FIRST OBJECT URL.
          {
            "url": "https://edit.myhelsinki.fi/sites/default/files/2017-06/Tykkisluuppi_Diana.jpg",
            "copyright_holder": "",
            "license_type": {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "All rights reserved."
            }
          },
          {
            "url": "https://edit.myhelsinki.fi/sites/default/files/2017-06/Tykkisluuppi_Diana_2.jpg",
            "copyright_holder": "",
            "license_type": {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "All rights reserved."
            }
          },
          {
            "url": "https://edit.myhelsinki.fi/sites/default/files/2017-06/Tykkisluuppi_Diana_3.jpg",
            "copyright_holder": "",
            "license_type": {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "All rights reserved."
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": "myhelsinki:45",
          "name": "sea"
        },
        {
          "id": "myhelsinki:836",
          "name": "suomenlinna"
        },
        {
          "id": "myhelsinki:793",
          "name": "history"
        }
      ],
      "where_when_duration": {
        "where_and_when": "Suomenlinna, kesäkuusta elokuuhun",
        "duration": "N. 1h 45min"
      }
    }
  ],
  "tags": {
    "myhelsinki:45": "sea",
    "myhelsinki:793": "history",
    "myhelsinki:836": "suomenlinna"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking like this - demo https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-zhukovsky-icl60

**Suppose your state is like below**

```js
state = {
    items: {
      meta: {
        count: "96",
        next: "http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/activities/?limit=1&start=1"
      },
      data: [
        {
          id: "f67de4f6-d23e-49a7-b9dd-63d68df533a3",
          name: {
            fi: "Purjehdus 1700-luvun tyyliin tykkisluuppi Dianalla",
            en: "Cannon sloop Diana´s sailings",
            sv: "Seglingar med kanonslupen Diana",
            zh: null
          },
          source_type: {
            id: 3,
            name: "MyHelsinki"
          },
          info_url:
            "https://www.suomenlinnatours.com/en/cannon-sloop-diana?johku_product=7",
          modified_at: "2020-01-27T09:37:27.221Z",
          location: {
            lat: 60.145111083984375,
            lon: 24.987560272216797,
            address: {
              street_address: "Suomenlinna Tykistölahti Pier",
              postal_code: null,
              locality: "Helsinki"
            }
          },
          description: {
            intro: null,
            body:
              "<p>Luvassa on amiraali Chapamin tahdittama mielenkiintoinen laivamatka valistusajan Viaporiin. Dianan purjehduksien aikana nähdään Suomenlinnaa mereltä käsin ja kuullaan saaristolaivaston kiehtovasta historiasta. Osallistujat pääsevät halutessaan avustamaan 1700-luvun univormuihin sonnustautunutta miehistöä purjeiden nostossa ja laskussa, lisäksi muutama reipas pääsee mukaan soutuharjoitukseen.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Purjehdukset lähtevät Suomenlinnan Tykistölahden laiturista. Suomenlinnaan pääsee JT-Linen vesibussilla tai HSL:n lautalla Kauppatorilta (venematka ei kuulu lipun hintaan). Diana on avovene, joten säänmukainen varustus on tärkeä.&nbsp;<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<span><span>Lasten meriseikkailu – perhepurjehdus ajalla 26.6.- 3.8.2019<br />\r\nkeskiviikkoisin, torstaisin ja lauantaisin kello 12.30<br />\r\nElokuun lauantaisin 10.8., 17.8., 24.8. ja 31.8.2019 kello 12.30.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nPurjehdus 1700-luvun tyyliin – yleisöpurjehdus ajalla 26.6.- 3.8.2019:<br />\r\nKeskiviikkoisin, torstaisin ja lauantaisin kello 15.30<br />\r\nElokuun lauantaisin 10.8., 17.8., 24.8. ja 31.8.2019 kello 15.30</span></span><br />\r\n&nbsp;</p>\r\n",
            images: [
              // FROM HERE I WANT TO SHOW FIRST OBJECT URL.
              {
                url:
                  "https://edit.myhelsinki.fi/sites/default/files/2017-06/Tykkisluuppi_Diana.jpg",
                copyright_holder: "",
                license_type: {
                  id: 1,
                  name: "All rights reserved."
                }
              },
              {
                url:
                  "https://edit.myhelsinki.fi/sites/default/files/2017-06/Tykkisluuppi_Diana_2.jpg",
                copyright_holder: "",
                license_type: {
                  id: 1,
                  name: "All rights reserved."
                }
              },
              {
                url:
                  "https://edit.myhelsinki.fi/sites/default/files/2017-06/Tykkisluuppi_Diana_3.jpg",
                copyright_holder: "",
                license_type: {
                  id: 1,
                  name: "All rights reserved."
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          tags: [
            {
              id: "myhelsinki:45",
              name: "sea"
            },
            {
              id: "myhelsinki:836",
              name: "suomenlinna"
            },
            {
              id: "myhelsinki:793",
              name: "history"
            }
          ],
          where_when_duration: {
            where_and_when: "Suomenlinna, kesäkuusta elokuuhun",
            duration: "N. 1h 45min"
          }
        }
      ],
      tags: {
        "myhelsinki:45": "sea",
        "myhelsinki:793": "history",
        "myhelsinki:836": "suomenlinna"
      }
    }
    }
```

```
  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    let images = items ? items.data[0].description.images : [];
    console.log(items.data[0]);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>List of items</h2>
        {images.map((image, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <img src={image.url} alt="imageicon" />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Or get all images using javascript.

```js
let results = {
      meta: {
        count: "96",
        next: "http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/activities/?limit=1&start=1"
      },
      data: [
        {
          id: "f67de4f6-d23e-49a7-b9dd-63d68df533a3",
          name: {
            fi: "Purjehdus 1700-luvun tyyliin tykkisluuppi Dianalla",
            en: "Cannon sloop Diana´s sailings",
            sv: "Seglingar med kanonslupen Diana",
            zh: null
          },
          source_type: {
            id: 3,
            name: "MyHelsinki"
          },
          info_url:
            "https://www.suomenlinnatours.com/en/cannon-sloop-diana?johku_product=7",
          modified_at: "2020-01-27T09:37:27.221Z",
          location: {
            lat: 60.145111083984375,
            lon: 24.987560272216797,
            address: {
              street_address: "Suomenlinna Tykistölahti Pier",
              postal_code: null,
              locality: "Helsinki"
            }
          },
          description: {
            intro: null,
            body:
              "<p>Luvassa on amiraali Chapamin tahdittama mielenkiintoinen laivamatka valistusajan Viaporiin. Dianan purjehduksien aikana nähdään Suomenlinnaa mereltä käsin ja kuullaan saaristolaivaston kiehtovasta historiasta. Osallistujat pääsevät halutessaan avustamaan 1700-luvun univormuihin sonnustautunutta miehistöä purjeiden nostossa ja laskussa, lisäksi muutama reipas pääsee mukaan soutuharjoitukseen.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Purjehdukset lähtevät Suomenlinnan Tykistölahden laiturista. Suomenlinnaan pääsee JT-Linen vesibussilla tai HSL:n lautalla Kauppatorilta (venematka ei kuulu lipun hintaan). Diana on avovene, joten säänmukainen varustus on tärkeä.&nbsp;<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<span><span>Lasten meriseikkailu – perhepurjehdus ajalla 26.6.- 3.8.2019<br />\r\nkeskiviikkoisin, torstaisin ja lauantaisin kello 12.30<br />\r\nElokuun lauantaisin 10.8., 17.8., 24.8. ja 31.8.2019 kello 12.30.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nPurjehdus 1700-luvun tyyliin – yleisöpurjehdus ajalla 26.6.- 3.8.2019:<br />\r\nKeskiviikkoisin, torstaisin ja lauantaisin kello 15.30<br />\r\nElokuun lauantaisin 10.8., 17.8., 24.8. ja 31.8.2019 kello 15.30</span></span><br />\r\n&nbsp;</p>\r\n",
            images: [
              // FROM HERE I WANT TO SHOW FIRST OBJECT URL.
              {
                url:
                  "https://edit.myhelsinki.fi/sites/default/files/2017-06/Tykkisluuppi_Diana.jpg",
                copyright_holder: "",
                license_type: {
                  id: 1,
                  name: "All rights reserved."
                }
              },
              {
                url:
                  "https://edit.myhelsinki.fi/sites/default/files/2017-06/Tykkisluuppi_Diana_2.jpg",
                copyright_holder: "",
                license_type: {
                  id: 1,
                  name: "All rights reserved."
                }
              },
              {
                url:
                  "https://edit.myhelsinki.fi/sites/default/files/2017-06/Tykkisluuppi_Diana_3.jpg",
                copyright_holder: "",
                license_type: {
                  id: 1,
                  name: "All rights reserved."
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          tags: [
            {
              id: "myhelsinki:45",
              name: "sea"
            },
            {
              id: "myhelsinki:836",
              name: "suomenlinna"
            },
            {
              id: "myhelsinki:793",
              name: "history"
            }
          ],
          where_when_duration: {
            where_and_when: "Suomenlinna, kesäkuusta elokuuhun",
            duration: "N. 1h 45min"
          }
        }
      ],
      tags: {
        "myhelsinki:45": "sea",
        "myhelsinki:793": "history",
        "myhelsinki:836": "suomenlinna"
      }
    }
    let images = results ? results.data[0].description.images : [];
    let urls = images.map(image=>image.url);
    console.log(urls);
```

Comment: Thanks Vahid. You and @Abhishek's solutions work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What I can see from the JSON data is, inside the `images` array there are 3 different objects and each has a `url` key in it.

So when using the map function on the array of images `list.description.images.map((img, index) =>` `img.url` shall give the url for each of the object in the array.

Instead of `src={img.url[0]}` try `src={img.url}`.

And if you want to access only the first object from the array, you can drop the map method and directly use `list.description.images[0].url`.

Comment: I have to use map method. there are hundreds of data.

Comment: in that case, use `{list.description.images.map((img, index) => {
                          return (
                            <img
                              src={img.url}` .

This way it will render images corresponding to each url of the objects in array. And if you want to show same image (first image) for each item in array, you can do it this way:
`{list.description.images.map((img, index) => {
                          return (
                            <img
                              src={list.description.images[0].url} ...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to render only one image, you do not need the second `map`.

So, instead of:

```html
          <div className="Box">
            {list.description.images.map((img, index) => {
              return (
                <img
                  src={img.url[0]} //IN HERE I TRY TO SHOW FIRST OBJECT
                  alt="pics"
                  style={{ width: "270px", height: "270px" }}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
```

use:

```html
          <div className="Box">

                <img
                  src={list.description.images[0].url}
                  alt="pics"
                  style={{ width: "270px", height: "270px" }}
                />

          </div>
```

edit: to avoid errors in case of items that do not have any images you can check like:

```html
          <div className="Box">
            { list.description.images && list.description.images[0] &&
                <img
                  src={list.description.images[0].url}
                  alt="pics"
                  style={{ width: "270px", height: "270px" }}
                />
             }
          </div>
```

or:

```html
          <div className="Box">
                <img
                  src={(list.description.images && list.description.images[0]) ? list.description.images[0].url : ''}
                  alt="pics"
                  style={{ width: "270px", height: "270px" }}
                />
          </div>
```

Comment: It does not work. It gave me error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"